# Why won’t Jenkins running on my Mac connect to a local git repo?

Tags: xcode, git, jenkins

I am trying to implement automated builds using Jenkins for my iOS projects. I added the Git plugin, but as soon as I try to put the URL for git in the git configuration for the project, it is showing the error in the screen shot below. Here Jenkins cannot clone from the repo to its workspace.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: I think Jenkins runs under it's own user account, so it probably doesn't have permission to access your home folder. Either make you home folder readable for the jenkins user, or move your repo.

Comment: yes you are right. the git clone command work only if i login as admin user in terminal, the same command will give me an error if i login as jenkin. Is that the normal work around? ie change the folder permission.

Comment: i tried to change the folder permission, but still it is not working.

Comment: What did you change the permissions to? Did you ensure that they applied recursively?

Comment: yes i applied it recursively ie change the repo permission to the user "jenkins"

Comment: yes i changed the permission recursively no the permission as follows. drwxr-xrwx+  6 jenkins  staff   204 Jan 22 09:58 test1 . same for inner files also

Comment: The "Does not appear to be a git repository" message usually means git can see the directory but there's not git repository in it.  Are you sure you have the right path?

Comment: get it is a git folder .git is folder there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i solved the issue . it was because of the permission the remote git is not updating properly

Answer (score 1):

For the "Repository URL" field it is expecting a remote repository URL, something like `git@github.com:github/hubot.git`. It will use that url to copy down code to run the job against.

If you just want to run a job in a particular directory where you already have the code you want to work against, then leave this section empty. You can set the directory that you want to run a job in by
1. scroll to the "Advanced Project Options" section
2. click "Advanced"
3. Check "Use custom workspace"

For one off things, this is fine, but if you use this a lot, I think you'll find it more useful to commit your code to github and have jenkins clone down a fresh copy of code for each run.

Comment: issue is not that because that folder is initialized with git --bare init only. Actually i solved the issue . it was because of the permission the remote git is not updating properly

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error if you miss the following cases:

1. Whenever the clone URL is wrong.
2. When you are trying to clone from a place where you don't have the 
   access to git server.
3. Whenever your Pem key is not added to the list of keys on the git
   server.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases git bare repo has extension .git
I mean (other)/test1 dont look correct, i think it should be (other)/test1.git had this same error on my mac.